# Gnuplot key opaque background

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to move the legend of a plot in `gnuplot` partially outside the plot area. It seems however that the plot border is visible inside the legend, even if I set the legend property to `opaque`.

A minimum example showing the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -persistent
set key at 11,1.02 box opaque
plot sin(x)/x
```

So, I wonder how I should go about in order to make the entire interior of the key opaque white? I've thought about putting a white rectangle behind it, but it seems to be a kind of dirty solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `opaque` option of the key does indeed draw a white rectangle, but the border is drawn on top of the key. Use `set border back` to draw the border behind the key:

```
set key at 11,1.02 box opaque
set border back
plot sin(x)/x
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an option to set the key color directly; people tend to resort to either drawing a box under the key (as you were thinking) or [more complicated methods](http://gnuplot-surprising.blogspot.com/2011/10/round-corner-key-box-in-gnuplot.html).

One workaround is to get rid of the plot border for the top and right edges of the plot (since the information there is redundant anyway):

```
set border 3
set tics nomirror
plot sin(x)/x
```

Another possibility is simply moving the key--does it need to be right on the edge of the plot? It could be further inside or outside.